# WCF custom datatype as OperationContract parameter

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm very new to WCF and have a question that I hope you can help me with.

**Project**: I've been asked to create a WCF service that allows a client to be able to upload a word file along with some metadata.

The client doesn't have a sample of the POST call they'll be making so I can't create a class off of that WSDL, but the post would contain data like this:

```
{
    author: 'John Doe',
    pages: '32',
    size: '14432',
    authToken: '322222222233',
    encoding: 'binary'
    name: 'Document1.doc'
}
```

I'm thinking of creating an **[OperationContract]** such as bool UploadFile(**CustomDocument** inputDocument) instead of bool UploadFile (string author, string encoding ....).

**My question**: If I use a custom object as an input parameter (**CustomDocument**) for an [OperationContract] would the client be able to pass all the information as string, int etc in its service call, or would they have to first create an instance of CustomDocument on their end, and then include that object in the post?

Sorry, I'm very new to WCF, my apologies in advance if this question doesn't make any sense; I'll update it based on your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that CustomDocument is a Serializable object and have a public parameterless constructor.
The easiest way is share the dll that contains the class CustomDocument between the WebService and the Application that will use it.
But personally when I try to send a complex object to a WebServce I prefer to serialize as a byte array and then Deserialize inside the WebService.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you; I'll look into this; however, i have a feeling the client wouldn't be excited about having to serialize. I'll stick with multiple params approach in this case. Thanks once again; I have some reading to do now.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the custom object `CustomDocument`. Suppose you have this service

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyTestServce
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
       UriTemplate = "/Upload?author={author}&pages={pages}&size={size}&name={name}&authToken={authToken}")]
    void Upload(string author, int pages, long size, string name, 
                string authToken, 
                Stream file);
}

public class MyTestService : IMyTestServce
{
    public void Upload(string author, int pages, long size, string name, 
                       string authToken, 
                       Stream file)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("author={0}&pages={1}&size={2}&name={3}&authToken={4}", author, pages, size, name, authToken));
        Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(file).ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

You can easily call it like

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var content = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(filename);
await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:8088/Upload?author=aa&pages=3&name=bb&authToken=112233", content);
```

**PS:** You need to use *webHttpBinding* (or *WebServiceHost* if it is not hosted in IIS).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply with example; I really appreciate it and found it extremely useful. I'll use your approach for my solution.

Comment: Quick silly question. In the public void Upload() example you gave, can I actually specify int, long etc as types or do all of them have to be strings? I'm just wondering if I should just specify the param datatype in the method, or just receive all as string (except the file stream) and then parse/validate to make sure its meets the requirements.

Comment: @SelfPreservation I tested above code before posting it. It works. Said that, using int,long or string, it depends on you. Use whatever you like. All would work.